# Asp.net SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Há uma pergunta parecida com essa, mas é diferente ..... minha duvida é  onde encontrar onde ela recebe essa informação.. fica no formulario da view? ou controller?

Há varias  Partials views que passam informação pro mesmo controller, como encontrar, a que esta causando esse erro?

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_dbo.Laudoes_dbo.Empreendimentoes_EmpreendimentoId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "EngosEngenhariaContext-20180626101342",
>   table "dbo.Empreendimentoes", column 'EmpreendimentoId'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

Comment: O Erro ocorreu em seu back-end (Server). Aparetemente, no momento da inserção, você ta tentando referenciar um ID que não existe na tabela Empreendimento. Certifique-se se o ID que voce esta tentando referenciar ja esta cadastrado